# Django is failing to save data related to User table. It says it doesn't have `mymodel_set` attribute

Tags: python, django

I have a model linked to Django `User` model but when I try saving to that model using `User` instance, it says **'User' object has no attribute 'mymodel_set'**

**My models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)
```

**My views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import mymodel

def register(request):
    #gets data here from template
    user = User(username=reg_username, password=reg_password)
    user.save()
    user.mymodel_set.create(name= display_name)
    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

Comment: Just use mymodel only instead of mymodel_set

Comment: Tried that and it say `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /myapp/register/
User has no users.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the related object existed, you would use `mymodel`, but it does not exist and the relationship is void, so it cannot be accessed via the `user`. Create it first and set the relationship to that user:

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.create(name=display_name, user=user)
#                                                   ^^^^ set related user
```

The `_set` suffix is usually used for reverse `ForeignKey` relationships and not for `OneToOne` relationships.

Also note that the `related_name` on the user field was already specified as `mymodel`, and the related field can now be accessed from the `User` model via  `user.mymodel`

Comment: Tried that and it said `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /myapp/register/
User has no users.` I have earlier deleted my **db**, *migration folder* and recreated all of them anew.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question but I was treating this wrongly, thinking it was `ForeignKey` relationship. Ese sir.